# No bootable Device with two RAID1

Tags: raid, boot, dell, dell-poweredge, sas

I have an DELL Poweredge R310. Configured are two RAID1 with 1TB each. My bootable device is on BAY 2 and 3. If I add the other RAID 1 in Bay 0 & 1 it can't find the bootable Device. How can I change the Boot Order of the Raid Controller so it will try to boot from the second RAID on BAY 2 & 3 ?

Raid Controller: SAS6IR with LSI Corp Config Utility for DELL SAS 6 v.6.22.03.00

I know that the server is not the newest one, but I really can't find any Information about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAS 6/iR controller is old enough that connection order matters - the controller can only boot from the drives with the lowest ID (slot number), regardless of what you do with the boot settings. If you swap the drives currently marked PD 2 and PD 3 into slots 0 and 1, you should be able to boot and see the new drives as expected.

This is also mentioned on page 50 of the manual:
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-sas-6ir-intgtd-and-adptr/manuals

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible via DELL utilities, from controller boot firmware (usually accessible via pressing F12 at some point of booting) or IPMI.

Also you can just use LSI tool named megacli. It will work with any LSI controller. You can download it [here](http://www.avagotech.com/support/download-search/?productFamilyName=%206Gb/s%20SATA%20@%20SAS%20RAID&area2=All;MegaRAID%20SAS%209240-4i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209240-8i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209260-16i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209260-4i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209260-8i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209261-8i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209266-4i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209266-8i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209270-8i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209271-4i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209271-8i;MegaRAID%20SAS%209271-8iCC;MegaRAID%20SAS%209280-16i4e;MegaRAID%20SAS%209280-24i4e;MegaRAID%20SAS%209280-4i4e;MegaRAID%20SAS%209280-8e;MegaRAID%20SAS%209286-8e;MegaRAID%20SAS%209286CV-8e;MegaRAID%20SAS%209286CV-8eCC;&area3=Management%20Software%20and%20Tools&area4=&dnd-keyword=). As you can see, the tool is universal for all SATAIII/SAS controllers. You will need "MegaCLI 5.5 P2". They have rpm package included. For deb-based os you can use alien or other tools, but in fact it is statically linked binary, so you can just extract it and run binary.

First of all, list all your logical drives:

```
megacli -LDInfo -Lall -Aall
```

For every configured virtual drive you will get output.

```
Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 278.875 GB
Mirror Data         : 278.875 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Cached, Write Cache OK if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Cached, Write Cache OK if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Is VD Cached: Yes
Cache Cade Type : Read Only
```

Then you just select needed drive as bootdrive. For drive 0 (L0) from adapter 0 (a0) that will be

```
megacli -AdpBootDrive -Set -L0 -a0
```

Of course than means you need to boot server one way or another. If you don't have OS on it, or it is not bootable, just create bootable flash with some linux on it.